# Replacing a fan fixture with a light fixture

Tags: electrical, lighting, ceiling-fan

My fan had a dual pole light switch... one for the fan, and one for the light.
So the ceiling has 4 wires coming from it.  One is a white ground, one a white wire, another red, and another black.

My light fixture has only 2 wires plus a ground.
What do we do with the red, black and white wires?

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the ceiling box?

Answer (score 4):

Ground (**bare, green or green/yellow**) can only be a ground.

You need one neutral/return, and it must be a **white or gray** wire, so that's your white.

You need one "switched-hot" wire.  Electrical code says you can use any color not already mentioned.** An often-used convention is that a switched-hot is the color other than black, i.e. red.

The remaining wire gets capped off at both ends. Put a smallish wire-nut (e.g. orange if you have it) and hold it on with a few loops of tape; as wire-nuts are prone to falling off single wires.

---

** outside of certain industrial installations.  The general idea is that electricians should measure instead of assume.

Comment: Not to make things more difficult, but if you want the same setup as before, some new fans will have a cardboard or plastic shield beneath the wires which reveals a wire nut which can be removed to power the fan separately.